# setInterval that executes AJAX to update a textare wont work on IE8

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, internet-explorer-8, setinterval

I have a web page that is used as a live log for a `txt` file being updated on Unix. I'm sending Ajax request to a PHP file that reads the file and returns its text to a `textarea`.

I want the `textarea` to be updated every 1 second.

The javascript code is:

```
<script>

    var myVar;

    function readLogAjax()
    {
        var account = document.getElementById("account").value;
        var env = document.getElementById("env").value;
        var type = document.getElementById("type").value;

        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("result").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
                console.log('Updated textarea');
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_file_reader.php?account="+account+"&env="+env+"&type="+type ,true);
        console.log('Sending request');
        xmlhttp.send();
        console.log('Sent request');
    }

    function startRead()
    {
        myVar = setInterval(readLogAjax,1000);
    }

    function stopRead()
    {
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }

</script>
```

the `textarea`:

```
<textarea  style="margin: 2px; height: 335px; width: 661px;" name="result" id="result" cols="80" rows="10" onclick=""></textarea>
```

And i have two buttons to start and stop the log:

```
<button type="button" id="generate"  onclick="startRead()">Run EVT</button>
<button type="button" id="generate"  onclick="stopRead()">Stop EVT</button>
```

This simple code works just fine on Chrome, and the `textare` is being updated every one second, i can see the Ajax calls in Chrome's network monitor:

[image: Network monitor]
But on IE8 (I must get this working on IE8), the `textarea` is only updated after the first time im entering the page and pressing *Run EVT*.

I thought this is a caching problem so i've added these meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

But this didnt help, so Im guessing this is some sort of a problem with the AJAX calls, I've added the console calls, and I see these result on the IE8 Console:

```
...
...
LOG: Sending request
LOG: Sent request
LOG: Updated textarea
LOG: Sending request
LOG: Sent request
LOG: Updated textarea
...
...
```

I've also tried a few modification of `setInterval` such as `setInterval("readLogAjax();",1000);` and `setInterval(function(){readLogAjax()},1000);`. But non of this helped

I cant figure what is the problem on IE8...

Comment: Have you logged or alerted `xmlhttp.responseText` to see if it actually contains a sensible value?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is of the top of my head, but another thing you are going to want to consider is only sending the full file once and then sending diffs after that. Faster, less bandwidth.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes, i've added it, and the text being returned is always the same, though the file is constantly updated on the Unix (it is the first text being returned just as i press the button for the first time)... seems like a problem with the ajax being returned, but i don't have any idea what is the cause.

Comment: It looks like there's still a caching issue. Make sure you have emptied IE's cache after you've added the meta tags. IE (and especially the older ones) do have very aggressive caching. The Javascript code itself seems to look okay, especially since the log shows that the requests are fired and the textarea is updated. I'd focus on the cache.

Comment: Older IE are notorious for cache problems when it comes to AJAX GET requests. You could try and see if using POST instead makes a difference – or simply add a “cache-busting” parameter to the URL, f.e. the current timestamp value (Date), to make it a _new_ URL each time that the browser _can not_ have cached already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Finally found the answer to the mystery...

IE8 was also caching the PHP file that was reading the text (`ajax_file_reader.php`), thus the only text that was displayed was the first one received, and from that on it was cached.

The solution was adding these headers to the PHP code:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.
```

Thanks *GolezTrol* and *CBroe* for focusing me on the caching issue.